# Will referencing UIApplication or the AppDelegate window property from iOS Framework cause an app to be rejected from the App Store?

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad

I'm concerned that one of the Frameworks that I'm using as part of my app, which references UIApplication and more specifically the `window` property on the AppDelegate. Is there an issue here regarding Apple policy?

I'm trying to make a Floating Action Button (in a Framework) as easy as humanly possible to add to an App.

Answer (score 0):

No , you can do anything inside the frameWork but not to violate processing phase such as listening to lock on/off , all frameworks use `UIApplication` such as when app is in background they use UIApplication to check state and so on